# Numpy isin() accounting for repeated elements

Tags: numpy, random

**Back story**

I am writing a script to simulate dice rolls. (n x 6-sided dice, at the moment)

The rolls are done using the line `np.random.randint(low=1, high=6, size=n)` which is working fine. e.g. producing:

`[1,4,5,2,4,4]`

For each roll, I want to check if certain combinations of dice are present, e.g.

- 6 threes: `[3,3,3,3,3,3]`
- 3 fours: `[4,4,4]`
- exactly 1 of each number: `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`

If the roll was checked against these three combinations, the result would be `False`, `True`, `False`, respectively.

**Question**

What is the most efficient way to check if a roll of n dice contains a given combination of dice, that:

1. Can have repeating numbers (e.g. 3 twos, or 4 fives)
2. Can be any length between 2 and n (i.e. all the dice or just some of them)

I've tried creating `set`s, and using `numpy`'s `isin()` and `in1d()`, but, as far as I can tell, none of these methods can recognise combinations of *repeated digits*. If you check whether 3 fours are in the roll, then it will just check the first four 3 times, and rolls with 1 or 2 fours will still be marked `True`.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It depends on what exactly you want to check. e.g. whether a roll contains 3 fours can be expressed as `list(rolls).count(4) == 3`

Comment: What should be the output for `[1,4,5,4,4,4]` and `[4, 4, 4]`? Would you have `True` since you have at least three 4s or `False` since you have more than three 4s?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

a = np.array([1,4,5,2,4,4])
comb = np.array([4,4,4])

c_a = Counter(a)
c_comb = Counter(comb)

c_comb <= c_a
# True
```

If you want to benefit from numpy's speed you could leverage `numpy.unique` to perform the count:

```
from collections import Counter

a = np.array([1,4,5,2,4,4])
comb = np.array([4,4,4])

c_a = Counter(dict(zip(*np.unique(a, return_counts=True))))
c_comb = Counter(dict(zip(*np.unique(comb, return_counts=True))))

c_comb <= c_a
# True
```

##### using [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas)

Here are two approaches whether or not you want an exact match or at least the combination:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.Series([1,4,5,4,4,4]).value_counts()
comb = pd.Series([4,4,4]).value_counts()

# exact match
a.reindex_like(comb).sub(comb).eq(0).all()
# False

# at least the combination
a.reindex_like(comb).sub(comb).ge(0).all()
# True
```

Comment: `Counter <= Counter` also returns True if the roll contains more than the desired amount.

Comment: @mkrieger1 which seems fine, no? `[4, 4, 4]` is in `[4, 4, 4, 4]`

Comment: I interpreted the question that they want to check whether *exactly* 3 fours are in the roll, not *at least*. But that is somewhat unclear.

Comment: Well, in this case one should filter the common keys and check for equality, but I'd be surprised that this is the case, if you play Yahtzee you can certainly count a Yahtzee as a Full House for instance ;)

Comment: @mkrieger1 added a pandas approach for both (it can be done with `Counter` but I find pandas more elegant in this case) ;)

Comment: many thanks @mozway for the answer. and mkrieger for the clarifications. In this case, it doesn't need to be the exact number, it is at least that number